# Will google analytics show up visits if used apk on emulator

Tags: android, google-analytics

I am trying to use google analytics for android app. I opened app couple times on emulator through eclipse. Than i also made an apk and opened it on my cell phone. But still when i go to google analytics it shows 0 visits? My question is how long does it take for google analytics to show the visits? Is there any way to test or check if my code has been installed in app correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have the correct permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

You can debug if it's working by checking network traffic to see if it's calling out to Google.  While Mr. Zurg is correct that data may take a while to appear in Analytics, with the advent of Real Time, you should be able to watch that screen and see hits come in almost instantly to help you debug this.

Answer (score 0):

Analytics data can be anywhere from a few hours to a day late. Installing the apk on an emulator won't change the total or active install counts in the android market. If you're tracking number of visits manually (with Analytics) though, that should register even on the emulator.